# "Invalid source address" exception when sending SMS using SMPP Server

Tags: smpp, oracle-soa, oracle-enterprise-manager

Everything was working fine for us from last 8 months and suddenly we started getting this error.

We configured SMPP driver properties in Oracle EM console and sending SMS using UMS integrated with Oracle SOA server.

Found a link related to this error but it doesn't help:

https://support.nowsms.com/discus/messages/485/1176.html

> [2017-10-17T10:33:16.806+05:30] [WLS_SOA] [ERROR] [SDP-25700]
>   [oracle.sdp.messaging.driver.smpp] [tid: Workmanager: , Version: 0,
>   Scheduled=false, Started=false, Wait time: 0 ms\n] [userId:
>   OracleSystemUser] [ecid:
>   49d20b62a8084325:-5336381e:15f247fea2f:-8000-000000000001c322,0] [APP:
>   usermessagingdriver-smpp] An unexpected exception was caught.[[
>   oracle.sdp.messaging.driver.DriverException: Invalid Source Address[a]
>     at
>   oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver.send(SMPPDriver.java:1073)
>     at
>   oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver.send(SMPPDriver.java:3268)
>     at
>   oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver.send(SMPPDriver.java:2849)
>     at
>   oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver.send(SMPPDriver.java:2724)
>     at
>   oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPManagedConnection.send(SMPPManagedConnection.java:95)
>     at
>   oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.DriverConnectionImpl.send(DriverConnectionImpl.java:41)
>     at
>   oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.dispatcher.DriverDispatcherBean.onMessage(DriverDispatcherBean.java:296)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1629.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy532.onMessage(Unknown Source)    at
>   oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.dispatcher.DriverDispatcherBean_xfokw2_MDOImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDOMethodInvoker.invoke(MDOMethodInvoker.java:35)
>     at
>   oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.dispatcher.DriverDispatcherBean_xfokw2_MDOImpl.onMessage(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.jmsmessagereceiver.ResourceAdapterImpl$RaMessageListener.onMessage(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:167)
>     at
>   oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.jms.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:73)
>     at
>   weblogic.work.j2ee.J2EEWorkManager$WorkWithListener.run(J2EEWorkManager.java:184)
>     at weblogic.work.DaemonWorkThread.run(DaemonWorkThread.java:30)
>
> ]] [2017-10-17T10:33:16.807+05:30] [WLS_SOA] [NOTIFICATION]
>   [SDP-26003] [oracle.sdp.messaging.driver.dispatcher] [tid:
>   Workmanager: , Version: 0, Scheduled=false, Started=false, Wait time:
>   0 ms\n] [userId: OracleSystemUser] [ecid:
>   49d20b62a8084325:-5336381e:15f247fea2f:-8000-000000000001c322,0] [APP:
>   usermessagingdriver-smpp] Dispatcher sent message with id:
>   eb50c4cdc0a800ab12d5fbbdbbbbd46a.

**Network Logs (Using Wireshark):**

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We figured out and resolved this issue. Posting its resolution here. May be it can help someone other and save their precious time.

**SMPP driver configured in Oracle EM console has a bug due to which Source address and Default source address are always null even if you pass it from driver configurations.**

> It was due to multiple Source Address at SMSC and our system was passing null
>   value in Source Address field. Due to this SMSC was not able
>   to recognize correct source address and throw "Invalid Source
>   Address" exception.
>
> If single/static source address is configured at SMSC then you can
>   pass null values and SMSC will automatically recognize source address.